# Wrap wpdb in try and cach

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress 5.3.

I'm trying to write to the database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
currencies (date, char_code, name, nominal, value)
VALUES
... "
```

The code is so far:

```
try {
    $result = $wpdb->query($sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    stop;
}
```

Note, this is all about inserting multiple rows. So, `$wpdb->insert` is not applicable here.

**The problem**: this code doesn't catch the exception. False is assigned to `$result`. But with debug = on exception is written on the screen:

> Duplicate entry '2019-11-26-BYN' for key 'PRIMARY'] INSERT INTO
> wp_ved_currencies (date, char_code, name, nominal, value)
> VALUES('2019-11-26', 'BYN',

How can I catch this exception?

Comment: @GayanSMuthukumarana: thanks for wanting to improve questions here. However, please don't add code formatting or bold to material that doesn't need it - it doesn't make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an error is returned by the database, $wpdb stores this error in the last_error attribute.

```
try {

    $result = $wpdb->query($sql);

    if ($wpdb->last_error) {
        throw new Exception($wpdb->last_error);
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    stop;
}
```

Maybe you consider to read aboud $wpdb->hide_errors() and         $wpdb->show_errors() as well.

Answer (score -2):

Please see this reference for this it would get help you out:

[Wp-Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)